# List of Map filter results in an extra empty item

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have a simple Class as follows:

```
public class ListOfMapsExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map1 = Map.of("aa1k", "aa1v", "aa2k", "aa2v", "aa3k", "aa3v");
        Map<String, String> map2 = Map.of("bb1k", "bb1v", "bb2k", "bb2v", "bb3k", "bb3v");
        Map<String, String> map3 = Map.of("cc1k", "cc1v", "cc2k", "cc2v", "cc3k", "cc3v");

        List<Map<String, String>> maps = Arrays.asList(map1, map2, map3);

        List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps1 = maps.stream()
                .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("aa1k") || map.getKey().equals("bb2k"))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("listOfMaps1 :: " + listOfMaps1);
    }
}
```

Expected output:
`listOfMaps1 :: [{aa1k=aa1v}, {bb2k=bb2v}]`

Actual output:
`listOfMaps1 :: [{aa1k=aa1v}, {bb2k=bb2v}, {}]`

**Question:**
Even though the third map doesnt pass filter criteria why its showing up as empty in the result? How can I omit it?

Comment: Add another filter for `listOfMaps1` by checking if the entry is empty or not.

Comment: Perhaps better code formatting would improve your Question.

Comment: Every Map in the `maps` List is converted to another Map after keeping only key-value-pairs where the key is either `"aa1k"` or `"bb2k"`. Since only the first two maps contain kvp's with these keys, the third Map of the output will be empty.

Comment: Aside: You might want to rethink if you really want to collect to `List<Map<String, String>>` or simply `Map<String, String>` or `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are building maps by filtering on each ones contents.  And one of them will be empty since no values were passed (but you still created it).  So you need to filter on empty maps before adding it to the list.

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps1 = maps.stream()
        .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(map -> map.getKey().equals("aa1k")
                        || map.getKey().equals("bb2k"))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(),
                        p -> p.getValue()))).filter(map->!map.isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("listOfMaps1 :: " + listOfMaps1);
```

Comment: Offtopic: "aa1k".equals(map.getKey()) would be better than map.getKey().equals("aa1k")

Answer (score 2):

Problem is already explained in WJS's answer, but based on your example you probably can use alternative (and IMO little more readable) solution:

- flatten stream to iterate over entries from all maps,
- from that stream filter entries which we are interested in
- wrap data from filtered entries back into Map
- collecting all such maps in a list.

Demo:

```
List

List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps1 = maps.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) //to create single stream of all entries
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("aa1k") || entry.getKey().equals("bb2k"))
        .map(entry -> Map.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output: `listOfMaps1 :: [{aa1k=aa1v}, {bb2k=bb2v}]`.

Comment: Is there a way we can sort this list by keys?

Comment: There is  one subtlety.  The maps are being processed independently of one another.  So duplicate keys across maps aren't a problem.  But in  your case, if one of the maps does have duplicate keys, a third map will be created to handle it.  Of course, no one knows the constraints or nature of the data or if there are no duplicates.

Comment: @AjayKumar Yes. simply add `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))` before wrapping entries in Map, so probably after `.filter(...)`.

Comment: @WJS I think I see what you mean. I was under impression that each *resulting* map should always contain single key-value pair, but OP code depending on input and filtering (like if he is searching for `a` `b` and `c`) it is possible to also get as result something like `[{a-a1, b-b1},{c-c1}]` while my code would generate `[{a-a1}, {b-b1}, {c-c1}]`.

Comment: You are awesome @Pshemo. Yes that worked. !

Comment: @AjayKumar Please note that code from this answer is not equivalent of what you have. For instance if you want to filter `a`, `b`, `c` keys and one map contains two of them as result you may get something like `[{a-a1, b-b1},{c-c1}]` while my code will generate `[{a-a1}, {b-b1},{c-c1}]`.

Comment: @Pshemo  Yeah.  That's what I got when I tested it.  But your answer would be cleaner otherwise.  I guess only the OP can make that decision based on their intimate knowledge of the data.

Comment: Yeah. I realized it now too. Your answer is perfect. !